# Find the index position of duplicate entries in a comma separated string

Tags: c#, linq

My problem just got more complicated than I thought and I've just wiped out my original question... So I'll probably post multiple questions depending on how I get on with this.

Anyway, back to the problem. I need to find the index position of duplicate entries in string that contains csv data. For example,

FirstName,LastName,Address,Address,Address,City,PostCode,PostCode, Country

As you can see the Address is duplicated and I need to find out the index of each duplicates assuming first index position starts at 0.

If you have a better suggestion on how to do this, let me know, but assuming it can be done, could we maybe have with a dicitionary>?

So if I had to code this, you would have:

```
duplicateIndexList.Add(2);
duplicateIndexList.Add(3);
duplicateIndexList.Add(4);

myDuplicateList.Add("Address", duplicateIndexList);

duplicateIndexList.Add(6);
duplicateIndexList.Add(7);

myDuplicateList.Add("PostCode", duplicateIndexList);
```

Obviously I don't want to do this but is it possible to achieve the above using Linq to do this? I could probably write a function that does this, but I love seeing how things can be done with Linq.

In case you're curious as to why I want to do this? Well, in short, I have an xml definition which is used to map csv fields to a database field and I want to first find out if there are any duplicate columns, I then want to append the relevant values from the actual csv row i.e. Address = Address(2) + Address(3) + Address(4), PostCode = PostCode(6) + PostCode(7)

The next part will be how to remove all the relevant values from the csv string defined above based on the indexes found once I have appended their actual values, but that will be the next part.

Thanks.

T.

### UPDATE:

Here is the function that does what I want but as I said, linq would be nice. Note that in this function I'm using a list instead of the comma separated string as I haven't converted that list yet to a csv string.

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> duplicateEntries = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

int indexPosition = 0;
foreach (string fieldName in Mapping.Select(m=>m.FieldName))
{
 string key = fieldName.ToUpper();
 if (duplicateEntries.ContainsKey(key))
   {
      List<int> indexes = duplicateEntries[fieldName];
      indexes.Add(indexPosition);
      duplicateEntries[key] = indexes;
      indexes = null;
   }
 else
   {
     duplicateEntries.Add(key, new List<int>() { indexPosition });
   }
 indexPosition += 1;
}
```

Maybe this will help clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. Use `.Select` on the resulting array to project a new `IEnumerable` of objects that contains the index of the item in the array along with the value.
2. Use either `ToLookup` or `GroupBy` and `ToDictionary` to group the results by column value.

Seems like an [`ILookup<string, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be appropriate here:

```
var lookup = columnArray
    .Select((c, i) => new { Value = c, Index = i })
    .ToLookup(o => o.Value, o => o.Index);

List<int> addressIndexes = lookup["Address"].ToList(); // 2, 3, 4
```

Or if you wanted to create a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> dictionary = columnArray
    .Select((c, i) => new { Value = c, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(o => o.Value, o => o.Index)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList());

List<int> addressIndexes = dictionary["Address"]; // 2, 3, 4
```

**Edit**

(in response to updated question)

This should work:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> duplicateEntries = Mapping
    .Select((m, i) => new { Value = m.FieldName, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(o => o.Value, o => o.Index)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList());
```

Comment: Hi, would you mind expanding this if instead I had a list instead of a comma separated string? I'd live to see my options. I've just finished writing a small function and will post the code, but in this function, it's using a list instead. Thanks

Comment: Sure, just replace `columnArray` with your list (as long as it contains the column names and implements `IEnumerable`). In other words `var lookup = yourCollectionName....`

Comment: Amazing!!! I worked a charm! I love to see what can be done with linq!! Just have to learn how to use it better!! Fanstatic code!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like :

```
int count = 0;
var numbered_collection =
    from line in File.ReadAllLines("your_csv_name.csv").Skip(1)
    let parts = line.Split(',')
    select new CarClass()
    {
        Id = count++,
        First_Field = parts[0],
        Second_Field = parts[1], // rinse and repeat
    };
```

This gives you Id's per item. (and also skip the first line which has the header). You could put it in a method if you want to automatically map the names from the first csv line to the fields).

From there, you can do:

```
var duplicates = (from items in numbered_collection
    group items by items.First_Field into g
    select g)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

Now you have all the groups where you actually have duplicates, and you can just get the 'Id' from the object to know which one is the duplicated.